# Save all records from one table column in an array

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, list

I want to store all records from a MySQL table column in an array (C#).

E.g. if there is the column "name" in a table:

| name | other column | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter |  |  |
| Marc |  |  |
| Henry |  |  |

... I want to store these names as elements in an array/list programmatically. The goal is to be able to access each element (in this case name) itself and going on with that.

Using a MySqlDataReader didn't work out that good, because it only returned me the last record in the column:

```
conn.Open();
string getNameQuery = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
MySqlCommand getName = new MySqlCommand(getNameQuery, conn);
dataReader = getName.ExecuteReader();
while(dataReader.Read())
{
    dataReader.getString("name");
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Simply create a new List<string>() then .Add() to it within the loop.

Comment: By the way, you should put your connection, command and reader objects in `using` blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `List` and add the values to it.

```
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
while(dataReader.Read())
{
    ls.Add(dataReader.GetString("name"));
}
```

Also, as I suggested, if you need only `name` column then write the query `SELECT  name FROM myTable`. There is no need to fetch other columns.

Comment: @Steve thanks for suggestion, I just copy pasted the OP's code